# Format specifies type "unsigned long" but the argument has type "int"

Tags: ios, objective-c, format-specifiers

Format specifies type "unsigned long" but the argument has type "int"

I get this error in XCode and no matter what format specifier I put in or if I change to NSInteger, NSUInteger, long or int, still get errors!? How can I fix this?

In

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

{

I have these lines, in line 2 is the error at @"%lu",(row % max)

```
NSUInteger max = (NSInteger)[self.calendar maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour].length;
[lblDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(row % max)]]; 
lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 9):

For `NSInteger` you should use `%td` or `%tu` for `NSUInteger`

See this link for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: ok, seems xcode is happy with %td although it was suggestion something else all the time. Thanks !

Comment: Xcode suggested architecture-specific fix where `%t` substitutes the right thing for the current architecture - glad it worked

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to following:

```
NSUInteger max = (NSInteger)[self.calendar maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour].length;
[lblDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(row % max)]]; 
lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a format specifier that matches to the NSUInteger type, like %tu, or cast the result of (row % max) to an int.

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems xcode is happy with %td although it was suggesting something else all the time. Thanks !